# Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm have a table with 'cellid' 'date'(datetime) and 'block'(real) columns.

I'm trying to find all the id's which had block > 1 for the last 3 days.

I'm currently doing it like this:

```
cells = npar.db.execute("SELECT cellid FROM data WHERE block > 1 AND date=?", (files[0][1],)).fetchall()
cells1 = npar.db.execute("SELECT cellid FROM data WHERE block >1 AND date = ?", (files[1][1],)).fetchall()
self.common(cells,cells1)
cells1 = npar.db.execute("SELECT cellid FROM data WHERE block >1 AND date = ?", (files[2][1],)).fetchall()
self.common(cells,cells1)

print len(cells)
def common(self,a,b):
    for item in a:
            if item not in b:
                a.remove(item)

b = npar.db.execute("SELECT cellid FROM data WHERE block > 1 AND date >= ? GROUP BY cellid HAVING COUNT(cellid) = 3", (files[2][1],)).fetchall()
        print len(b)
```

len(b) is not equal to len(cells)

Comment: Your "HAVING COUNT(cellid) = 3" clause makes no sense. Your last query would only select those cellids who has exactly three occurances in which block > 1 and date >= your time limit.

Comment: That is exactly what I want, I wanted to know why it does not equal len(cells)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"for the last 3 days"? So the following could work?

```
cells = npar.db.execute("SELECT cellid FROM data "
                        "WHERE block > 1 "
                        "AND date >= ? "
                        "GROUP BY cellid "
                        "HAVING COUNT(*) = 3", (files[0][1],)).fetchall()
```

Comment: I realized that my original algorithm was wrong in the first place.
I needed to find the common elements among those 3 queries, after i corrected it I got 352 results, how ever with your query, I get only 282 results...